# GPUImage: Way to output tiled images?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I use GPUImage (https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) in my iOS project and really like it.

Now I use it to process image with a filter (only color changes, no scaling/transform), and use the layer from the `GPUImageView` output to do something else, so my chain looks like:

`GPUImagePicture` -> (Color Filter) -> `GPUImageView`.

Now I want to change the output to be tiled images, where the rendered result will be used as a pattern. I had considered few ways to do it:

1. Just use Quartz2D to generate tiled images to `GPUImagePicture`, then process it (so the result will also be tiled). But since `GPUImagePicture` will redraw using Quartz2D again, it could be less efficient. Am I right?
2. Modify or subclass `GPUImageView` to generate tiled result using OpenGL. It could be hard and I cannot figure out a good way to implement it.

Which will be better and is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I follow what you want to do with the images here, but have you looked at using a GPUImageCropFilter to break the image into smaller pieces? You could add multiple crop filters, each responsible for a different region, to the last stage of your filter chain. Each of these crops would generate a tile from the image.